# Определить наличие тега ссылки в строке с помоью регулярного выражения

Tags: php, php7

Потоянно приходит спам с ссылками внутри. Но ссылки могут указать пользователи, единственное что отличает от бота то, что бот добавляет тег ссылки. Помогите составить регулярку, чтобы определить наличие тега `<a href= ... />`
Делал проверку на https, эта не подходит:

```
if ( preg_match( '~(https?|ftp):\/\/\S+~', $value ) ) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Нашёл такую регулярку, возможно это ответа "/<a.*?href=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?>/i"

Comment: если вам проверить надо наличие тэга `<a` то зачем вы проверяете не это, а сам адрес?

Comment: @teran думал избавиться от спама так, но потом понял что пользователь может тоже оставлять ссылки. Этим кодом (проверка на протокол) привёл пример, чтобы какую-то картину представляли.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Нашёл регулярное выражение](https://snipp.ru/php/preg-match) следующего вида: `preg_match("/<a.*?href=["\'](.*?)["\'].*?>/i")`
тесты прошёл, думаю это решение